# Can't create grails Criteria query containing a belongsTo relation

Tags: grails, criteria, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I've been trying to create a criteria builder containing a belongsTo relation and have yet to succeed. Consider the following model:

```
class Msg {
    ...
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
    ...
}  

class User {
    ...
    Organisation organisation
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to make the following query:

```
Msg.createCriteria().list() {
    ...
    user {
        eq("organisation", organisationInstance)
    }
    ...
}
```

All I'm getting is the following error

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - No signature of method: static User.call() is applicable for argument types: (MsgService$_findMessages_closure1_closure6) values: [MsgService$_findMessages_closure1_closure6@afcba8]
Possible solutions: save(), wait(), any(), getAll(), save(java.lang.Boolean), save(java.util.Map)
```

I've tried to add different small additions to the criteria query like:

```
join "user"
fetchMode("user", org.hibernate.FetchMode.EAGER)
```

But still get the same problem.

I even tried to add the following static mapping to the Msg class:

```
static mapping = {
    columns {
        user lazy: false
    }
}
```

Still not working.

Is there a way to use criteria builder containing a belongsTo query at all?

Thanks for your help in advance.
Lucien

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the solution! The problem wasn't related to criteria builder at all. In this instance, I had a user variable inside the scope. Once a removed it it works like a charm :-)

Comment: it helped after banging my head for long time. Error doesnt gave any kind of clue regarding this issue. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Thank you!  I have run into this issue in the past, and I ran into it again just now.  Thanks for refreshing my memory.  Fool me twice...

Answer (score 2):

```
def criteria = Msg.createCriteria()
results = criteria.list{
    user{
        eq("organisation", organisationInstance)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference from the example above?

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled.. It should of course contain a "()". Correcting.